# Field 'product_id' doesn't have a default value

Tags: php, laravel

This is how my image and product model looks like. When i try to save my image, i get the error

> General error: 1364 Field 'product_id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into product_images (path, updated_at, created_at) values

The image path is submitted but the product id is not submitted. Also when i do `$product->images()->create(['product_id',=>$product'url_path' => $file_name]);`, i get an error but then, the data is being saved in the database (which i know is obviously not the right way)

Why is this happening?

**Image**

```
protected $fillable = ['product_id', 'url_path'];

public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
}
```

**Product**

```
public function images()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Image::class);
}
```

**Controller**

```
$product = Product::findorfail($id);
if ( $request->hasFile('image'))
{
    $path =  $request->file('image')->store('public/pics');

    $file_name = $request->file('image')->hashName();


    $product->saveProduct($request);

    $product->images()->create(['url_path' => $file_name]);
```

Comment: It's a hasMnay relation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using `product_id` in the images table, the relationship must be `hasMany`:

```
return $this->hasMany(Image::class);
```

Comment: the path is saved but then i can't find the image in the `store('public/pics');` folder

Comment: @Switz it's not related to the original question. If you can't solve this new problem with saving an image, please create a new question and post all related information there.

Answer (score 0):

Open your database and check images table.

```
  product_id field is null select.
```

Try now

Answer (score 0):

I have already met this kind of error but I settled it by putting the field in question in nullable. Look in your migrations and put the 'product_id' in nullable

```
$table->integer("product_id")->nullable()
```

This error occurs because you try to save data with a field that takes a null value when it must be filled

I hope it helped you in the opposite case tell us